# Squid reverse proxy follow redirects

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, squid

I've managed to get squid running as a reverse proxy with URL rewriting:

http://example.com.proxy.myserver.com

will be reverse proxied to

http://example.com

So far, so good. But, when http://example.com responds with a redirect to http://www.example.com the browser follows this redirect.

I'm looking for a way, to rewrite that redirect like this:

http://www.example.com.proxy.myserver.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it is not possible with squid 3.x

```
location_rewrite_program

    Not yet ported from 2.6
```

That's a bummer. Any other ways?